# Add quantiles to geom_density plot with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78202817/how-to-use-stat-summary-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-density-plot-in-ggplot2/78203881#78203881) about using `stat_summary` to add a vertical line for the median value in my density plot.  I'm now trying to adapt this to also add vertical lines for the 95% confidence interval.  I've been using another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077199/how-to-use-r-ggplot-stat-summary-to-plot-median-and-quartiles) as the base for my code, but it doesn't add any lines to my plot.  How can I get this to work?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

dat <- data.frame(
  site = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 25),
  sex = rep(c("f", "m"), 50),
  mass = rnorm(100, 50, 5)
)

dat |>
  ggplot(aes(x = mass, col = sex)) +
  geom_density() +
  stat_summary(
    aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0),
    fun = mean, geom = "vline", orientation = "y"
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0),
    fun.min = function(pred) { quantile(pred, probs = 0.025) }, 
    fun.max = function(pred) { quantile(pred, probs = 0.975) },
    geom = "vline", orientation = "y", linetype = "dashed"
) +
facet_wrap(~site)
```

Comment: Remove `orientation = "y"`.  But you'll also have to make other changes to get what you want...  [It would have been helpful to report the warning you get with your current code: "Removed 8 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (`geom_vline()`)" is a big clue to what's going on.]

Comment: Note the 95% quantiles are not the same thing as a 95% confidence interval (presumably for the mean). How exactly do you want to interpret these lines?

Comment: @Limey any idea what the other changes are?  If I remove orientation = "y", I get a lot of vertical lines!

Comment: @MrFlick, hmmm... ok, I'm trying to show what values fall within the CIs, so if I can't use the quartiles, how should I do this?

Comment: If you look at the answer I've just posted, you'll see that I do!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
dat |>
  ggplot(aes(x = mass, col = sex)) +
  geom_density() +
  stat_summary(
    aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0),
    fun = mean, geom = "vline", orientation = "y"
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    data = dat %>% 
      group_by(site, sex) %>% 
      reframe(
        tibble(
          value = quantile(mass, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)), 
          prob = c(0.025, 0.975)
        )
      ),
    aes(xintercept = value, col = sex),
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~site)
```

gives

[image]

Personally, I find overriding the `data` argument of a `geom_xxx` call more intuitive than calling `stat_summary` and `after_stat`.

This code gives you what (I think) you expect your code to do.  But I support MrFlick's warning about whether it's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Limey. I'm still holding out hope for an example for how to do this within `stat_summary`.